# Accessing Play instances through a Load Balancer

Tags: playframework

I have created a Play! Application which is working fine. 
Eg:
 I creted a login page when submitted it will take to a frontpage module's loginCheck method which validates and redirect to a inner page.

I have 6 instances of play running in the machine.

I created Load Balancer Play application in another machine. Which will point to any one of the instance at a time. I want to use the Load Balancer for DB request and Web request too.

DB Request - It just updates the DB and ends there.

Web Request - It(LoadBalancer) has to send the request to the instance it will have a response which i will display in the web page through the LoadBalancer.

For Eg:
  For the First web request will render the login page. so i send the request as web.
It will send to the instance and response (Login page) is returned. Which i am able to render.

My Problem is the login page form submit will take to frontpage module's logincheck method which is not inside LoadBalancer Application. i wanted to send the page back to the instance with those post values through LoadBalancer how can i do that.

```
(Key -> Server = play )                 

         Request                                        Request                                                   Request    
-------------------------->     |      LB      |------------------------------------> |   Play LB        |----------------------------> | Play Instance

<------------------------       |                |<-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
         Response                                                                                                   Response


LB - Load Balancer
```

Comment: Not really clear to me what you want to do here...

Comment: Wow, are you sure you want to write your own Load Balancer?! There are many out there!

Comment: @Stefano Can you give me some links for load balancer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We created a LoadBalancer using netty which is a open library. works fine.

Answer (score 2):

As per our comments..

Mind that I'm writing this into an answer because I could not fit these links into a comment, as it's not really an answer to your initial question!

Then, a quick question: are you just trying to write a Load Balancer out of interest, or are you sure your application will need one? A well configured machine can take up to several million requests without much issues.

Anyway, now about your question..

These are some precise links (as you'll see, quite broads because it really depend on whatt is your deployment environment, what exactly requires load balancing)

- A good introduction from [JavaWorld](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-10-2008/jw-10-load-balancing-1.html) - it's in two parts, 2nd one is more interesting
- [HAProxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/)
- [AWS Elastic Load Balancing](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/)
- [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19900-01/819-4740/index.html)

On stack overflow the [Load Balancing tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/load-balancing) is quite active; you can combine it with Java or more specific topics, eg: [Load Balancing on Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/load-balancing+java).

But I admit that's very broad.

Now, I pointed you to a few of the top LB in their /category/. It means that, depending on your REAL needs, the kind of solution (homebrewed or existing product) that you choose will be different.

First of all, load-balancing is a matter of **architecture**.. eg. going with an AWS or similar  solution is often a great idea when you want to write you application, but be able to start additional instances when your load grows.

But if you have an application with really many reads, and few writes, you might want to focus on distributing your database and configuring you Master-Slave and your application(s) to optimize read and writes.

Etc.etc.